# Complex mix of proprietary license and Apache 2.0 license with subfolders

Tags: license-compatibility, apache-2.0

I have a repo in GitHub which contains many different projects, each in its own folder and each folder having its own license.

Now at the root of project 5 is a restrictive proprietary license. There are no other files or executable in the root of this folder except a folder "src".

Under "src/resources/ui" is the complete code of project 5 and an Apache-2.0-license-file.

Under these circumstances, which license will apply for project 5, the restrictive proprietary license or the Apache-2.0 license?

The structure is shown below?

```
├── project-1
├── project-2
├── project-3
├── project-4
├── project-5
|   └── Proprietary-license-file (no other files except the src folder )
|       └──  src/resources/ui (contains Apache-2.0-license-file)
├── Apache-2.0-license-file
```

Answer (score 3):

The entire project is obviously intended to be under the restrictive proprietary license, while some (maybe all) of the components/libraries used are under the Apache license. But within this folder, which contains the file with the Apache license language, there may be other files with different --even proprietary-- licenses.

Hopefully there is a clear indicator (possibly SPDX) in each file indicating the applicable license, as well as the other required information (attribution, maybe notice file).

If this is your repo, then I suggest you add the necessary information so that it is clear and obvious for everybody.